# How can I create an arbitrary ranking of records in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

#### The Problem

**I'm looking to create a user defined ranking of records in Postgres.**

That is, the order in which the records are ranked is not defined by some underlying score but rather via the choices of a collection of users.

These choices are subject to frequent changes and the ranking will be constantly changing with both new records being added and existing records being moved to new positions.

For the sake of argument, assume that these operations occur with high frequency.

Furthermore, we need to be able to determine when given an arbitrary subset of all records, how they should be ordered according to the ranking.

#### A Naive Solution

A very naive solution would be to track the ranking as an integer directly on the model and 'push' all the higher ranked records up by one when inserting a new record.  This is obviously not ideal as we would need to modify potentially the entire table at once.

#### A Better Solution

Maintain a 'score' on each record in the interval `[0, 1]`.  This can be indexed using a BTREE and used to rank the records.  The first two records would have the scores `0` and `1`.  When inserting a new record some intermediate value would be chosen (e.g. `0.5`) and the record inserted.  This choice could be optimised in order to minimise the number of digits in the score.

### A Question

The above seems like a complex solution to a common problem.  Furthermore, the problem is actually being solved by the underlying BTREE index with the score something of a hack to create the index.

**Is there a neater way to solve the problem?**

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the ranking is not decided by a metric like votes, but rather by "add new record or move a record above or below another record" ? How many records inserted/updated per second do you expect? Do you need to know the rank of any record without doing any counting (fast) or with counting (slow)?

Comment: Is it not possible that the order of two posts changes after they have been ranked for the first time?

Comment: Hi, the idea is that there is no natural score that will denote rank.  

The best way to explain it is to imagine a UI that permits users to drag and drop a list of records as well as to add new records (so orders can be expected to change).  No additional context is available with which to rank the records.

While the actual use case would involve relatively few changes per second, I am curious to see what the solution would be for a more demanding dataset.